# Trouble With Sticky Nav Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

My nav on a custom page is located below a header photo. When the page scrolls, I'd like for the nav to stay sticky at the top. However, I cannot get it to stay in a fixed position. I feel like I've tried about everything. Wonder if something in my code is conflicting with the script to not allow it to function.

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="images/header-1.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;"/>
</div>
<div id="headerTitle">
    <h2>header</h2>
    <h3><em>subhead</em></h3>
</div>   
<nav id="navbar">
    <div id="enter">
        <div class="numberCircle"><span>5</span></div>
        <div class="pg-nav">
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
                <li><a href="#d">D</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<style>
#navbar {
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
width: 100%;
}
.fixedtop {
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
}
#enter {
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: #696969;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto auto;
height: 30px;
line-height: 10px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: #97233f solid 2px;
/* width: 100%; */
/* z-index: 9999; */
}
.pg-nav {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}
.pg-nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 0 0 10px;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;  
display: inline-block;    
}
.pg-nav li {
float: left;
padding: 12px;
font-weight: 900;
}
.pg-nav li a {
display: block;
font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
color: #fff;
font-size: 11px;     
font-weight: 900;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;      
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
.pg-nav li {width:100%; padding:5px;}
}
.pg-nav li a:hover {
color: #97233f; 
}
.numberCircle {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 28px; 
font-size: 21px;
border: 2px solid #fff;
float: left;
}
.numberCircle span {
text-align: center;
line-height: 28px;
display: block;
color: #fff;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
var distance = $('#navbar').offset().top,
$window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
$('#navbar').toggleClass('fixedtop', $window.scrollTop() >= distance)
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have jquery included?

Comment: you need to add `margin-top: 0 !important;` to class `.fixedtop` style definition

Comment: Yes jquery-3.1.1.min.js and jquery-3.1.1.js

Comment: Why don't you place your `navbar` component at the top of your html? or you need it to be below headers for some reason? I also don't understand why are you trying to use javascript, surely this is just a css issue. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That would make things easier since I can then just use position:fixed; for the navbar. I wanted to try a design with the headline and a photo at the top similar to this page: www.uconnhuskies.com/sports/w-baskbl/2016champs/index.html. From what I can tell, the JavaScript allows for the header to have that movement from below the header to sticky at the top. Unless there's a simpler way to do that in CSS that I don't know about?

Comment: I have my script src at the bottom within the <body> tag.

Comment: @TimurMamedov If you think you've got an amazing answer on Q, then you allowed to apply your talents in the section below to be highly appreciated. Or not. If the author knew your solution, or something better, he wouldn't have asked about what he is asking.

Comment: @Banzay sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I understand the ultimate goal is to have a `navbar` stuck to the top of the page, even when scrolling?

My proposed solution might seem rather trivial, but I would suggest to change the order of `navbar` and `header`s in your HTML.

---

## **Potential solution**:

**HTML**

```
<nav id="navbar">
    <div id="enter">
        <div class="numberCircle"><span>5</span></div>
        <div class="pg-nav">
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
                <li><a href="#d">D</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="header">
     <img src="images/header-1.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;"/>
</div>

<div id="headerTitle">
     <h2>header</h2>
     <h3><em>subhead</em></h3>
</div>
```

**RESULT**

[image]

---

Do correct me if I didn't quite understand the premise of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the script src tags from the bottom of  tag to the  and that worked. I was able to keep the navbar below the header graphic and image.